# Variable numbers not updating in my if else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to run this simple banking "app", but I can't get the values to update properly. I've tried prompting userDesposit by pressing "d" as my first input and then prompted userBalance by pressing "b", but the value would always be alerted as 0 no matter what number I enter. Also on my first run through, I can't get it to quit after prompting some choices - but I can get it to quit right away if I were to press "q" as my first choice. Can someone help me fix these? Thanks!

```js
function userBank() { 
  let userBalance = 0;
  let continueBanking = true; 
  let userInput = prompt ("Enter 'q' to quit immediately, Enter 'w' to withdraw money, Enter 'd' to deposit money, Enter 'b' to view your balance.");
  
  while (continueBanking == true) {
    if (userInput == "w") {
      let userWithdraw = prompt ("How much would you like to withdraw?");
      userBalance = userWithdraw;
      userBank();
    } else if (userInput == "d") {
     let userDeposit = prompt("How much would you like to deposit?");
     userBalance = userDeposit;
      userBank();
    } else if (userInput == "b") {
      alert("Here is your current balance: " + userBalance);
      userBank();
    } else if (userInput == "q") {
      alert("Banking app is now closing.");
      continueBanking == false;
      return;
    }
    else {
      alert("Invalid user input. Try again.");
      return;
    }
  }
}

userBank();
```

Comment: There's no need for the `continueBanking` variable, since you return from the functon when you set it to `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call the function recursively. It already repeats because of the `while` loop. Each recursion level has its own copy of the `userBalance` variable, which is initialized to `0`.

The recursion also makes it hard to get out of the application. You have to enter `q` as many times as it has recursed.

You just need to move the prompt for the action inside the loop instead of calling the function again.

You're also not adding and subtracting the amounts that the user deposits and withdraws, you're simply setting the balance to them.

```js
function userBank() {
  let userBalance = 0;

  while (true) {
    let userInput = prompt("Enter 'q' to quit immediately, Enter 'w' to withdraw money, Enter 'd' to deposit money, Enter 'b' to view your balance.");
    if (userInput == "w") {
      let userWithdraw = prompt("How much would you like to withdraw?");
      userBalance -= parseFloat(userWithdraw);
    } else if (userInput == "d") {
      let userDeposit = prompt("How much would you like to deposit?");
      userBalance += parseFloat(userDeposit);
    } else if (userInput == "b") {
      alert("Here is your current balance: " + userBalance);
    } else if (userInput == "q") {
      alert("Banking app is now closing.");
      break;
    } else {
      alert("Invalid user input. Try again.");
    }
  }
}

userBank();
```

Comment: To add to this, you're probably also not wanting to _assign_ `userBalance` to the deposit or withdrawal amount; rather you'll want to _add_ and _subtract_.

Comment: I was just fixing that while you commented.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Because you call it recursively after the deposit, you always zero the account before they ask for the balance.

Do this instead:

```
let userBalance = 0;

function userBank() {
```

For the exit condition do this:

```
let userBalance = 0;

function userBank() { 
  const userInput = prompt ("Enter 'q' to quit immediately, Enter 'w' to withdraw money, Enter 'd' to deposit money, Enter 'b' to view your balance.");
      if (userInput == "w") {
      let userWithdraw = prompt ("How much would you like to withdraw?");
      userBalance = userBalance - userWithdraw;
      return userBank();
    } else if (userInput == "d") {
      let userDeposit = prompt("How much would you like to deposit?");
      userBalance = userBalance + userDeposit;
      return userBank();
    } else if (userInput == "b") {
      alert("Here is your current balance: " + userBalance);
      return userBank();
    } else if (userInput == "q") {
      alert("Banking app is now closing.");
      return;
    }
    else {
      alert("Invalid user input. Try again.");
      return userBank();
    }
  }
}

userBank();
```

You're welcome!

When you find yourself repeating code, however, it is sign that you are recreating the operation of a machine over a data structure, manually - rather than defining the data structure and writing the machine:

```
let userBalance = 0;

function loop(balance) { 

   const userInput = prompt ("Enter 'q' to quit immediately, Enter 'w' to withdraw money, Enter 'd' to deposit money, Enter 'b' to view your balance.");

   const operations = {
      w: () => { 
         userWithdraw = prompt ("How much would you like to withdraw?");
         userBalance = userBalance - userWithdraw;
      },
      d: () => {
         let userDeposit = prompt("How much would you like to deposit?");
         userBalance = userBalance + userDeposit;
      },
      b: () => alert("Here is your current balance: " + userBalance),
      q: () => {
         alert("Banking app is now closing.");
         return 'QUIT';
      },
      invalid: () => alert("Invalid user input. Try again.");
    }

   const op = operations[userInput] || operations.invalidInput;

   return op() === 'QUIT' ? userBalance : loop()
}

loop();
```

Here you start to see the machine and the data.

The machine is "Select an operation and execute it, then repeat", and the data structure is "Operations that operate on a bank balance".

This can be refactored further, because the data (bank balance) is still mixed in with the operations machine. But this is the process of crystalising your program - making clear and separated the algorithms and data structures.

When you have them mixed, you end up with a lot of repeated code and more and more special conditions and hacks. And it becomes confusing, and fixing a problem with the loop ruins the bank balance, and vice versa. Hard to maintain or extend.

OK, I'll do one more cut, and try to make it into three distinct things: operations, a run loop, and a bank balance....

```
const operations = {
   w: (balance) => { 
      const withdrawal = prompt("How much would you like to withdraw?");
      return balance - withdrawal;
   },
   d: (balance) => {
      const deposit = prompt("How much would you like to deposit?");
      return balance + deposit;
   },
   b: (balance) => {
      alert("Here is your current balance: " + userBalance)
      return balance
   q: (balance) => {
      alert("Banking app is now closing.");
      return 'QUIT';
   },
   invalid: (balance) => {
      alert("Invalid user input. Try again.")
      return balance
   }
}

function atm(balance) { 
   const input = prompt(
      `Enter 'q' to quit immediately, 
       Enter 'w' to withdraw money, 
       Enter 'd' to deposit money, 
       Enter 'b' to view your balance.`
   );
   const op = operations[input] || operations.invalid;
   const newBalance = op(balance)
   return newBalance === 'QUIT' ? balance : atm(newBalance)
}

console.log(`The final balance is: ${atm(0)}`)
```

In this case, everything is cleanly separated. An operation is "a function that takes a number and returns a number of a QUIT signal".

The operations can each be tested. This is important, because you can prove each piece of the program independently:

```
operations.balance(100) // Should alert 100 balance and return 100
```

And modifying one operation will not break your program's control flow, because that is a simple machine that you can test independently.

The run loop is a machine that takes a balance, gets a user input, then applies an operation to the balance selected by the input, and calls the run loop with the new balance or quits.

You can break the program by not returning a balance from an operation - but once you add TypeScript, you can tell it that an operation must return a number or 'QUIT'.

Then the only type of bug left is not returning 'QUIT' from the quit operation, or not returning the correct mutation of the bank balance, which you can write tests for.

Then you can know that your program works, and you can write programs (tests) that prove that it still works when you make changes to it.

Comment: Because you call it recursively after the deposit, you always zero the account before they ask for the balance.

Comment: That comment should be in the answer.

Comment: But the recursive calls are wrong, because you have to enter `q` multiple times to get out.

Answer (score 0):

The prompt that assigns a value to userInput is outside of your while loop: You only get a value once, then you keep reprocessing that same value. Instead, you are recursively calling userBank(). Each time you do that, you get trapped in another loop processing the same input over and over.